Retorna None sin un error aparente
Esto es en una parte del codigo que estoy armando, de por medio en el codigo completo, clono un repositorio y edito el mismo Json (Contenido) para luego comitearlo, pero resulta que cuando hago una "suma" del diccionario con las respuestas retorna None
import json
    
    ubi = 'Ubicaciones de los archivos' 
    
    
    with open(f"{ubi}\\ActJson.json", 'r') as archivo:
        actualizacion=json.loads(archivo.read())#cargo el contenido de actualizacion, Diccionario con respuestas guardadas 
        archivo.close()
    
    with open(f"{ubi}\\contenido.json", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as archivo: #archivo Json previamente armado [{},{},{}]
        contenido = json.loads(archivo.read()) 
        archivo.close()
    
    print(contenido.append(actualizacion)) #esto retorna none


El print retorna none, y deberia sumar la actualizacion con el
diccionario ya obtenido.
Los archivos son correctos, ya los imprimi para checkearlos y tambien
con un type()}
El Json contenido es tipo lista y la actualizacion es diccionario.


Supongo que  contenido es una lista Python, por lo tanto estás usando list.append(). Éste método en una secuencia actua siempre in-place, agrega el item al final de la misma y no retorna nada, en realidad retorna None que es lo que retorna todo método en Python por defecto. append no retorna un nuevo objeto con el contenido agragdo.
print() simplemente está imprimiendo el retorno de append(), si quieres ver el contenido de la lista actualizada simplemente imprímela a ella:
contenido.append(actualizacion)
print(contenido)

Si quieres un nuevo objeto basta con usar el operador +:
# print(contenido + actualizacion)
nuevo = contenido + actualizacion
print(nuevo)

Algunas cositas más:

Es recomendable que siempre especifiques el encoding de todo archivo que abras. Lo haces en el segundo pero no en el primero. Si no lo haces el encoding depende de la plataforma.

En vez de json.loads() puedes usar directamente json.load().

Es recomendable que uses pathlib.Path.joinpath() u os.path.join() para concatenar las rutas.

Cuando usas with no tienes que cerrar el archivo explícitamente, ya se encarga el administrador de contexto de hacerlo por tí.


Es decir, puedes hacer:
import json
import pathlib

ubi = pathlib.Path('/Ubicaciones/de/los/archivos')

with open(ubi.joinpath("ActJson.json"), 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as archivo:
    actualizacion = json.load(archivo)
with open(ubi.joinpath("contenido.json"), 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as archivo:
    contenido = json.load(archivo)

contenido.append(actualizacion)
print(contenido)

o también:
import json
import pathlib

ubi = pathlib.Path('/Ubicaciones/de/los/archivos')

with (
    open(ubi.joinpath("ActJson.json"), 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as archivo_act, 
    open(ubi.joinpath("contenido.json"), 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as archivo_cont
):
    actualizacion = json.load(archivo_act)
    contenido = json.load(archivo_cont)

contenido.append(actualizacion)
print(contenido)


Gracias!
Sobre todo por el resto de las cositas agregadas, resulta que estaba tan segado con el codigo y tan confiado que el print me iba a retornar la lista y el diccionario sumado, MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS!!
También voy a tener en cuenta lo del cerrar los archivos, lo hacia solamente por buena practica.
